# In HTML, is it possible to partially format <input> or <textarea> box?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

Is it possible to partially format text in an `<input>` or a `<textarea>` box ?
When writting an email with Gmail, the content of the message can be formatted as in the following example:

[image: Example of formatted text in Gmail]

I know that I can find existing JS libraries to write message like in Stack Overflow, but I would prefer something like Gmail ([WYSIWYG](https://www.humblix.com/Yp90cGO/what-does-the-acronym-wysiwyg-stand-for)).

Comment: Take a look at something like [froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

Comment: You may use ckeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. All the WYSIWYG redactors uses the [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) attribute on `<div>` (or another element) and the [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) JS API to format the editor content.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Show an example of a bold text among a regular text in `<textarea>`

Comment: ah, I thought something else with the statement you can't.